# Notification on main menu when the new articles have posted

Tags: joomla-2.5

I'd like to include a notification "!" in my main menu when there is a new blog post. The blog page have already set up Recent order.

"!" will disappear after click - or disappear for a few days - whatever is easiest.

I have tried this link : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638618/main-menu-notification-if-there-is-an-article-update-joomla-2-5

but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the answer you linked to should work with a couple of changes.

1. Override `mod_menu` by copying `modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default_component.php` to `templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/mod_menu/default_component.php`
2. Add the following code right before `if ($item->menu_image)`:

   ```
   if($item->query['option']=='com_content' && $item->query['view']=='category' ){
     $date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 week")); //articles from up to 1 week ago
     $query="select id from #__content where state=1 and catid="
       .intval($item->query['id'])
       ." and publish_up >= '". $date . "'";
       $db=JFactory::getDbo();  
       $db->setQuery($query);
   if(count($db->loadAssoc())) $item->title.=' !';  
   }
   ```

Any *Category Blog* menu items will display an exclamation mark if there are (published) articles  from within the last week.

*Note*: this only works if you're using `mod_menu` to display your menu. Some templates (e.g. from RocketTheme and Shape5) uses their own menu system by default, but this can usually be changed in template settings).

Comment: Brilliant! At first it didn't work, when I went to template setting, ensure its off, it overwritten php again, so I forced update it again, now is working.

'code' $item->query['view']=='category' ) 

Is that category you can change it to specific name like 'help', not all menu? I got menus ID = 15, and 20, would that goes to catid=15, 20?

Do you know how to expire "!" after clicked once?

Comment: is it possible for the notification to remain for one week unless it is clicked? if it is clicked will the notification disappear? @johanpw

Comment: @JamesDC I'm sure it's possible, but I can't give you a simple answer. You'd have to create a code that checks if the current (logged in) user has read the article, and store this information in the database. Or maybe set a cookie when user X reads article Y. [This post] has a similar question with a couple of ideas.